# flask and android session

Tags: android, python, session, flask

> > I am sending a HTTP request to my flask server from my android application. Initially I create a session entry for my mobile client in my flask server as session['mobile_username'] = None in my home 'http://0.0.0.0:2800/' URL so when the user logs in it will be updated to his name. But the problem is when I make second request for my login function where I check whether the session['mobile_username'] returns key error no such key named 'mobile_username'. I know that the session is not synchronized but I need to know a solution how to handle the session between my mobile App and my flask server. Any help would be great.

My code:

```
import datetime
from flask import Flask, render_template, request, jsonify, flash, session, redirect, url_for
from flask import Session
from his.Models import db, GuestDetails, BookingDetails, RoomPriceDetails, RoomDetails, DiscountDetails
app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = "sqlite:///HIS.sqlite"


@app.route('/', methods=['POST', 'GET'])
def home():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        if request.form['device'] == 'Mobile':
            try:
                if session['mobile_username'] is not None:
                    return jsonify({'message': 'dashboard'})
                elif session['mobile_username'] is None:
                    return jsonify({'message': "Please login or sign up"})
            except KeyError:
                session['mobile_username'] = None
                print(session['mobile_username'])
                return jsonify({'message': 'home'})
    else:
        try:
            if session['username'] is not None:
                return redirect(url_for('dashboard'))
            elif session['username'] is None:
                return render_template('home.html', message="Please login or sign up")
        except KeyError:
            session['username'] = None
            return render_template('home.html')
        return render_template('home.html')
@app.route('/login', methods=['POST', 'GET'])
def login():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        if request.form['device'] != 'Mobile':
            if session['username'] is None:
                guest_id = request.form['id']
                print(guest_id)
                password = request.form['password']
                records = db.session.query(GuestDetails).all()
                IDs = [records[i].Guest_ID for i in range(len(records))]
                if guest_id in IDs:
                    d_password = db.session.query(GuestDetails).filter_by(Guest_ID=guest_id).first()
                    if password == d_password.Password:
                        session['username'] = d_password.First_name+" "+d_password.Last_name
                        session['user_id'] = d_password.Guest_ID
                        return redirect(url_for('dashboard'))
                    else:
                        return render_template('login.html', message="Password is incorrect")
                else:
                    return render_template('login.html', message="User id does not exist. Please sign up..")
            else:
                return redirect(url_for('dashboard'))
        else:
            if request.method == "POST":
                if session['mobile_username'] is None:
                    print(session['mobile_username'])
                    guest_id = request.form['id']
                    password = request.form['password']
                    records = db.session.query(GuestDetails).all()
                    IDs = [records[i].Guest_ID for i in range(len(records))]
                    if guest_id in IDs:
                        d_password = db.session.query(GuestDetails).filter_by(Guest_ID=guest_id).first()
                        if password == d_password.Password:
                            session['mobile_username'] = d_password.First_name + " " + d_password.Last_name
                            session['mobile_user_id'] = d_password.Guest_ID
                            return jsonify({'message': 'Successfully logged in', 'name': session['mobile_username']})
                        else:
                            return jsonify({'message': 'Password is incorrect'})
                    else:
                        return jsonify({'message': "User id does not exist. Please sign up.."})
                else:
                    return jsonify({'message': "dashboard"})
    else:
        return render_template('login.html')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.secret_key = 'super secret key'
    app.config['SESSION_TYPE'] = 'redis'
    db.init_app(app)
    with app.app_context():
        db.create_all()
    app.run(host="0.0.0.0", port=2800, debug=True, threaded=True)
```

Answer (score 1):

With all the levels of `if elif else` your code is quite hard to follow which could be what's tripping you up and causing some kind of logic error in your code. I would suggest trying to simplify your conditional logic so you can tell what's going on a little easier.

For example this:

```
if request.form['device'] == 'Mobile':
        try:
            if session['mobile_username'] is not None:
                return jsonify({'message': 'dashboard'})
            elif session['mobile_username'] is None:
                return jsonify({'message': "Please login or sign up"})
        except KeyError:
            session['mobile_username'] = None
            print(session['mobile_username'])
            return jsonify({'message': 'home'})
else:
    try:
        if session['username'] is not None:
            return redirect(url_for('dashboard'))
        elif session['username'] is None:
            return render_template('home.html', message="Please login or sign up")
    except KeyError:
        session['username'] = None
        return render_template('home.html')
    return render_template('home.html')
```

Can be simplified to:

```
if request.form['device'] == 'Mobile':
    if 'mobile_username' in session:
        return jsonify({'message': 'dashboard'})
    return jsonify({'message': "Please login or sign up"})
else:
    if 'username' in session:
        return redirect(url_for('dashboard'))
    return render_template('home.html', message="Please login or sign up")
```

Here's a very basic [flask session example](https://gist.github.com/spik3r/fa99b0a45cfed2f87d6570e55d70bd67) with similar behaviour.
If no session exists it'll print a link to /login, otherwise it'll print the session user.

Are you only having issues from android, or also with the none mobile request?

Comment: I tested in my android app it creates a session['mobile_username'] in my first request whereas in my second request it shows a KeyError('mobile_username' key does not persist) and the same works fine in my browser. So I don't know where I am going wrong.

Comment: If it's working from the browser have you tried removing the `if request.form['device'] == 'Mobile':` check? I would suggest you try to simplify the problem and get it to work incrementally. Are you sure the android request is correct and sending what you expect?